# I cant get data from this getElementbyId

Tags: javascript, html, function

HTML part... a To do list with 4 properties: the property "description" its not to be shown on the table. But when you dbclick on first cell(title), it should return all the 4 properties.

```
<body>
  <h1 id="h1">ToDo Lijst</h1>
   <label for="item">Titel</label><br>
   <input type="text" id = "Item"><br><br>
   <!--<p style="color:red; font-size:18px;" id="FoutInput"></p>-->
   <label for = "aantal">Omschrijving</label><br>
   <input class="desc" type="text" id="description"><br><br>
   <label for="person">Toegewezen Person</label><br>
   <input type="text" id = "person"><br><br>
   <label for="deadline">Deadline</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="deadline">     
   <button type = "button" onclick="Toevoegen()"><span>&#43;</span></button>
   <button type="button" onclick="Edit()" >Aanpassen</button>   
   <button style="background-color: crimson" onclick="Verwijderen()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>   
   <p style="color:red; font-size:15px;" id="FoutInput"></p>   
   <table id="table">
     <tr>         
         <th>Titel</th>
         <th>Toegewezen Person</th>
         <th>Deadline</th>         
     </tr>       
   </table>    
//javascript part
var rIndex,
    table = document.getElementById("table");

    
function Toevoegen()
{   
      var newrow = table.insertRow(table.length),
        cell1 = newrow.insertCell(0),
        cell2=newrow.insertCell(1),
        cell3=newrow.insertCell(2),
        Titel = document.getElementById("Item").value,
        person = document.getElementById("person").value,
        deadline = document.getElementById("deadline").value;
        //var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
    
    if(Titel != "" && person != "" && deadline != "")
    {
        
    cell1.innerHTML = Titel;
    cell2.innerHTML = person;
    cell3.innerHTML = deadline;
    document.getElementById("Item").value = "";     document.getElementById("person").value = ""; 
    document.getElementById("deadline").value = "";
    document.getElementById("description").value = "";    
    console.log(description);
    var text1 = "Toegevoegd!"; 
     document.getElementById("FoutInput").innerHTML = text1;        
   }       
           else{ 
                cell1 = newrow.deleteCell(0);
                cell2 = newrow.deleteCell(0,1);
                var text = "Veld(en) mag(mogen) niet leeg blijven!"; 
               document.getElementById("FoutInput").innerHTML = text;              
           }        
        selectedRowtoinput();
        selectedCell();   
        
}
function selectedCell(){      
    
    for(var i = 1;i<table.rows.length; i++){
    
    table.rows[i].cells[0].ondblclick = function(){    
       
        var titel = document.getElementById("Item").value;   
        var person = document.getElementById("person").value;
        var deadline = document.getElementById("deadline").value;
        var description = 
         document.getElementById("description").value;      
            
        console.log(description);        
        
    alert("overzicht:" + "\n" + titel+ "\n" + person+ "\n" + deadline + "\n" + "omschrijving: " + description);
    
   
    }
    }
    
}

function selectedRowtoinput()
{    
    for(var i =1; i< table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
            rIndex = this.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("Item").value =this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("person").value =this.cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("deadline").value =this.cells[2].innerHTML;
            
        }
    }
}
selectedRowtoinput();
```

I cant get data from:
var description =
document.getElementById("description").value;

```
    console.log(description);
```

I just get an empty line. I get the info from the other 3 except this one...

Comment: Unable to reproduce, it's working fine on my browser, you are probably doing something else wrong

Comment: What do you expect from `console.log(description);`?

Comment: I expect the value you enter in inputfield "description".

Comment: function selectedcell().. Iget all the values(var people, var feedback and var Titel but I cant the last one "description"... get an empty line if I console.log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've updated your code and alter it with logic, that you DO create cell for description, but make in hidden, so it is not visible, but still holds the data, check example

```js
var rIndex,
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    
function Toevoegen()
{   
      var newrow = table.insertRow(table.length),
        cell1 = newrow.insertCell(0),
        cell2=newrow.insertCell(1),
        cell3=newrow.insertCell(2),
        cell4=newrow.insertCell(3),
        Titel = document.getElementById("Item").value,
        person = document.getElementById("person").value,
        deadline = document.getElementById("deadline").value,
        description = document.getElementById("description").value;
        // Make hidden cell for description
        cell4.className += " hidden";
    
    if(Titel != "" && person != "" && deadline != "")
    {
        
    cell1.innerHTML = Titel;
    cell2.innerHTML = person;
    cell3.innerHTML = deadline;
    // Put data in hidden cell
    cell4.innerHTML = description;
    document.getElementById("Item").value = "";
    document.getElementById("person").value = ""; 
    document.getElementById("deadline").value = "";
    document.getElementById("description").value = "";    
    var text1 = "Toegevoegd!"; 
     document.getElementById("FoutInput").innerHTML = text1;        
   }       
           else{ 
                cell1 = newrow.deleteCell(0);
                cell2 = newrow.deleteCell(0,1);
                var text = "Veld(en) mag(mogen) niet leeg blijven!"; 
               document.getElementById("FoutInput").innerHTML = text;              
           }        
        selectedRowtoinput();
        selectedCell();   
        
}
function selectedCell(){      
    for(var i = 1;i<table.rows.length; i++){
    
    table.rows[i].cells[0].ondblclick = function(){    
       
        var titel = document.getElementById("Item").value;   
        var person = document.getElementById("person").value;
        var deadline = document.getElementById("deadline").value;
        var description = document.getElementById("description").value;            
        
    alert("overzicht:" + "\n" + titel+ "\n" + person+ "\n" + deadline + "\n" + "omschrijving: " + description);
    
   
    }
    }
    
}

function selectedRowtoinput()
{    
    for(var i =1; i< table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
            rIndex = this.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("Item").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("person").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("deadline").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("description").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;
        }
    }
}
selectedRowtoinput();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="h1">ToDo Lijst</h1>
   <label for="item">Titel</label><br>
   <input type="text" id = "Item"><br><br>
   <!--<p style="color:red; font-size:18px;" id="FoutInput"></p>-->
   <label for = "aantal">Omschrijving</label><br>
   <input class="desc" type="text" id="description"><br><br>
   <label for="person">Toegewezen Person</label><br>
   <input type="text" id = "person"><br><br>
   <label for="deadline">Deadline</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="deadline">     
   <button type = "button" onclick="Toevoegen()"><span>&#43;</span></button>
   <button type="button" onclick="Edit()" >Aanpassen</button>   
   <button style="background-color: crimson" onclick="Verwijderen()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>   
   <p style="color:red; font-size:15px;" id="FoutInput"></p>   
   <table id="table">
     <tr>         
         <th>Titel</th>
         <th>Toegewezen Person</th>
         <th>Deadline</th>         
     </tr>       
   </table>
```

Comment: The problem is on the function selectedcell()... I get all the data from "getElementeById"(var people, var titel and var feedback.... except the one for description...

Comment: Try now my example, but keep in mind - in `selectedcell()` you set `ondblclick` only on first cell of each row, so double click on first cell and you'll get `alert` pop up with `description` content

Comment: Thanks man... it works now!!! But why did it only work if I put var description outside the function? I didnt do it on the other ones(titel, people and feedback) and it it worked...

Comment: Updatet my example, check updated description. If this answer fully solve your problem, please set as solved)

Comment: I used "alert" to show the 4 properties..;if I want to use a "popover"... how and where do I have to add it?

Comment: Well, you just can swap alert with any other function, i.e. popover

Comment: thanks man, on w3schools, if you want to use popover... it seems to be moer complicated... I will try later... thanks for the help... where do I have to change it to solved?

Comment: thanx! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers